# mapred-site.xml.template is missing in Hadoop 2.9.0

Tags: hadoop

I'm a brand new user of this forum, Ubuntu, and Hadoop. I'm running Ubuntu on VirtualBox, and I've been following [a tutorial for installing and configuring Ubuntu and Hadoop 2.7.3](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1167462/Hadoop-Beginners-Guide-How-To-Install) (though I'm trying it with Hadoop 2.9.0) when I came across to a command which is giving me an error:

```
root@VirtualBox:/media/sf_hadoop-2.9.0# cp mapred-site.xml.template mapred-site.xml
cp: cannot stat 'mapred-site.xml.template' : No such file or directory
```

I've also found another link that says to replace the `cp` with `mv`, but it didn't work either and produced the same error as `cp`.

Why is the command giving me an error when the original author got no error in their tutorial?

Comment: Here is the link
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1167462/Hadoop-Beginners-Guide-How-To-Install

Comment: What is the output of `ls -alF /media/sf_hadoop-2.9.0/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.*`? Please edit your question, paste the results at the bottom, select the text you pasted, press the `{}` button in the editor, and save the edits.

Comment: I'm afraid I did not understand what you want me to do with this Is -alF command. But i typed and run in terminal and got error:
Is: command not found?

Secondly, I can't copy and paste the results here, because the machine is running into virtualBox so I can't directly copy that result here.

Comment: Please copy and paste the command into your terminal and then run it.

Comment: The error received is:
    ls: cannot access '/media/sf_hadoop-2.9.0/mapred-site.*' : No Such file or directory

Comment: Please don't type the command. Please copy and paste the entire command.

Comment: Sir, I can't copy and paste command directly. Therefore I added a note that my Ubuntu is installed in virtualBox.
I just typed the entire code you provided and it worked.
What now?

Comment: What filenames does it find?

Comment: Can I continue further steps of the link I provided in my question?

Secondly, the command you have changed for me, will it now effect the work, I'm working upon, as I've been using the command ls -alF /media/sf_hadoop-2.9.0/mapred-site?

Comment: `ls` won't affect your work.

Comment: Very Well,
Now that I run the command when I reached in the tutorial so it gives same error:
cp mapred-site.xml.template mapred-site.xml

cp: cannot stat 'mapred-site.xml.template' : No such file or directory

SAME ERROR

Comment: Yes, you have the same error. That's because `ls` doesn't affect your work, which includes not affecting it by solving the problem. What files are shown by `ls -alF /media/sf_hadoop-2.9.0/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.*`?

Comment: It has not shown any file bu a line appeard as:
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 758 14 04:28 /MEDIA/SF_HADOOP-2.9.0/ETC/HADOOP/MAPRED-SITE.XML.TEMPLATE*

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial left out a step (though not in a screenshot). We start in the middle of the tutorial, where it says:

> Get into “hadoop-2.7.3” folder and create a directory called “tmp”. The following commands do this:
>
> ```
> cd <hadoop-2.7.3 path>
> mkdir tmp
> ```
>
> In my case:
>
> ```
> cd /home/fazlur/hadoop-2.7.3
> mkdir tmp
> ```

In the screenshot below that, you can see those commands entered at the top:

[image: screenshot]

It continues:

> Edit “core-site.xml” file using the following command
>
> ```
> gedit core-site.xml
> ```

Notice, though, that in the screenshot, they run `cd etc/hadoop` in between `mkdir tmp` and `gedit core-site.xml`. They left that out of the instructions.

You should go back to that point in the tutorial, run `cd etc/hadoop` and continue from where it says `Edit "core-site.xml"`.

Comment: I picked up your point Chai.
But please tell me first that when I repeat all these steps with cd/ etc/hadoop so what will happen with those steps which I have already taken without cd etc/hadoop? I MEAN that is it ok, I mean that I am worry that some new problem rise later on due to this?

Comment: You shouldn't `cd etc/hadoop` (note that there's only one `/` in that) and then redo **all** your steps. You only need to `cd etc/hadoop`, then redo `gedit core-site.xml` (filling it in as the tutorial directs), then redo `cp mapred-site.xml.template mapred-site.xml`, then continue on with the rest of the tutorial.

Comment: I'm going to beging redoing things but I've noticed one more thing Chai. the etc/hadoop has been using since the beginning. When the HEADING Installing Hadoop starts so cd <HADOOP PATH> here the Author is using etc/hadoop.

Comment: That's not the case. After that, it says `Get into “hadoop-2.7.3” folder and create a directory called “tmp”.` That switches away from `etc/hadoop`.

Comment: Got a new error when saving a file after editing as:
Unexpected Error: Error renaming temporary file: text file busy

Comment: Secondly, as I told you that the Author of the tutorial has been using etc/hadoop since the Installing Hadoop starts.
But when I worked upon the file gedit hadoop-env.sh so I worked it without etc/hadoop so there was just a blank file where I appended JAVA Path but the actual was a full text file with lots of commands and I was suppose to append the java route to the end of the file. NOW that you mentioned the mistaken point i.e. to add cd etc/hadoop so I have to do the same thing for gedit hadoop-anv.sh.

Comment: SO WHEN I do etc/hadoop then it opens the exact file which has been shown in tutorial but when I add and save the file so it gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because there is no file named as mapred-site.xml.template in the latest version it has following files.
mapred-queues.xml.template

[As You can see in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maF7h.png)